# Is would ok in for this sequence of tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> I had not seen that film when I was a kid, even if at that time it was
>   very popular, I would see it later when I **would be** an adult

Just would like to know if **would**  is correct, I think so: when i was a kid it was future but now that I am an adult it is not future any more it was future in the past .
But if  the author  was still  a kid he would say  I will see it when I am an adult not when  I will be an adult so was may be better

Comment: Who told you that English has a conditional tense?

Answer (score -1):

The context of this sentence is that you are speaking as an adult, looking back on your youth. In this situation, because you are still an adult, it would be more idiomatic to say **when I became an adult**. To use **when I was an adult** suggests that you are no longer an adult although this construction might be used in some contexts.

**Would be an adult....** doesn't work at all. You are reflecting on the past and the natural tense in this context is the past tense, as in **became** or **when I grew up**.

The sentence might be rephrased as:

> I did not see that film when I was a kid, even though at that time it was very popular; I saw it later when I became an adult.

Simply to say **I saw it later** is matter of factual, a bit prosaic. The construction **I would see it later...** is also fine. It has a slightly different nuance, suggesting that you had the opportunity to see it later when you were an adult.

Note that you need a semi-colon or full stop (instead of a comma) to separate the two halves of your statement.

Comment: why is not possible to use past perfect(had seen) because at the time of writing i have seen that film so when I was a kid I had not seen it (yet)

Comment: @user5577 You can use it if you prefer. The choice of **past** or **past perfect** is frequently just a matter of preference. Note that the period when you did not see the film coincides with your youth. It did not occur before you were a kid.

Comment: So it could be understood as he had not seen the film before he was a kid so in this case past simple is better to clarify the meaning

Answer (score -1):

> I had not seen that film when I was a kid, even if at that time it was very popular, I would see it later when I would be an adult
>
> Just would like to know if would is correct, I think so: when i was a kid it was future but now that I am an adult it is not future any more it was future in the past .

---

Basically **your assumption is correct** however the sentence needs a little alteration

> I had not seen that film when I was a kid, even if at that time it was very popular, I would see it later when I would be an adult.

Here lets remove some clutter at the start of the statement, also I think to clarify things we need to say at what time you will see the film. **As an adult.**

As a kid, I had not seen the film, even though it was very popular, but I would see it later **as an adult.**.

You are talking as if you are in the past looking to what will happen in the future so the use of the **modal verb would** is required.

My Answer is  **would is correct.**

**As a kid, I had not seen the film, even though it was very popular, but I "would" see it later as an adult.**

---

would modal verb (FUTURE) [C.E. Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) used to refer to future time from the point of view of the past: